# distortion correction using vertex displacement

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

i'm trying to create a small VR demo with QT and OpenGL-ES for google Cardboard using vertex displacement, as described [here](https://ustwo.com/blog/vr-distortion-correction-using-vertex-displacement).
Short: It applys the brown conrady model to every vertice to counteract the lense distortion with following formula:

> x/y_distorted = x/y_undistorted * (1.0 + K1 * r^2 + K2 * r^4)

As coefficients I got K1 = -0.55 and K2 = 0.34 from the java Source Code for gvr.
Here is the relevant Shader code:

```
    vec4 tmp = vec4(a_position,1.0);
    tmp = uMVMat * tmp; //Applying the ModelView Matrix
    float r2 = dot(tmp.xy,tmp.xy); //Calculating the squared radius
    tmp.xy *= 1.0f + (-0.55+0.34*r2)*r2; //Applying the Formula to x and y

    gl_Position = uPMat * tmp;
```

This results in following picture when rendering a plane:
[Distorted Plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F54pu.png)

What am i doing wrong? I've even tried swapping the coefficients, inverting them, ... I always get just some kind of pincussion distortion..

Answer (score 1):

Just based on the Cardboard Distortion [vertex shader](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/blob/5a02da736744eb5970e04d36c251231a1f5ab201/Samples/CardboardDesignLab/ustwo-cardboard-unity/Assets/Source/Shaders/CardboardDistortion.cginc) it looks like you are missing the projection step where you divide by z^2. [Other](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/lenscorrection/) methods for barrel distortion assume NDC space.

```
// should be
float r2 = dot(tmp.xy,tmp.xy)/(z*z);
```

Also according the wiki page

> Barrel distortion typically will have a negative term for K1  whereas pincushion distortion will have a positive value

So your coefficients should be ok.